Question about JSON schema and syntax for... nested array?
I am struggling with a JSON schema used for API function calls (similar to the following but for a small scale project: https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/function-calling.html). In my case, I am trying to create a schema that would guide API calls to retrieve data on natural gas storage. The name of the schema would refer to the API function, and schema's parameter would be parameter specs for the API.
API: https://www.eia.gov/opendata/browser/natural-gas/stor/cap
The problem is with "facets" - there are four categories of facets, "duoarea", "process", "product", and "series". By selecting "duoarea" for example, I would be able to pick from the list, such as selecting "NUS" and "R48". I think this led to an array within an array, but I don't know enough about JSON to express it in the schema, leading to the wrong call being made.
My schema:
{
    "name": "NaturalGasStorage",
    "description": "Natural Gas Storage Capacity",
    "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "frequency": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Frequency",
                "enum": ["monthly", "annual"],
                "default": "monthly"
            },
            "data": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["value"]
                },
                "default": null
            },
            "facets": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["NUS", "R48"]
                },
                "uniqueItems": true,
                "default": null
            },
            "start": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Date. Example 2019-12-31",
                "default": null
            },
            "end": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Date. Example 2019-12-31",
                "default": null
            }
        },
        "required": ["frequency", "data"]
    }
}

It generated the following incorrect call - problem is in "facets" - it doesn't have "duoarea" - the data layer above "NUS" and "R48":
[
    {
        "name": "NaturalGasStorage",
        "parameters": {
            "frequency": "monthly",
            "data": ["value"],
            "facets": ["NUS","R48"],
            "start": "2022-12-31",
            "end": "2023-12-31"
        }
    }
]

The correct call is below - looks like I did not implement an array within array / nested array - in the API dashboard, I would need to select "duoarea", then it opens a selection to allow me to select "NUS" and "R48":
"parameters": {
    "frequency": "monthly",
    "data": ["value"],
    "facets": {"duoarea": ["NUS","R48"]},
    "start": null,
    "end": null,
}

What is the correct syntax in the JSON schema to permit the correct behavior (with "duoarea" in "facets")?
Thanks!
